# Google Earth not showing length of a KML file created with QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth

I have created a KML linestring file using QGIS. When opened with Google Earth, the file is  correctly shown. Anyway, if I try to see the length of the route, the measurements sheet is not present.

I am using QGIS 3.22.5

Thanks for any help.